# PHP Fatal error: Cannot make non static method WC_Shipping_Method::is_enabled() static in class enda_woocommerce_bundlerate_shipping

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have updated wooCommerce plugin that broke my wordpress site and getting this error in log.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot make non static method WC_Shipping_Method::is_enabled() static in class enda_woocommerce_bundlerate_shipping in server_path/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bundle-rate-shipping-1.3.8/bundle_rate.class.php on line 6
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin you're using, WooCommerce Bundle Rate Shipping, needs to be updated.

A quick Google search reveals that support for WooCommerce 2.6 (the current version of WooCommerce which you've updated to) was added to that plugin in version 2.0.0.

The error shows you're running version 1.3.8 of the plugin therefore you're missing the WC2.6 support, hence the issue.

The changelog for the plugin can be viewed here: https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-ecommerce-bundle-rate-shipping/1429243